# BaseExpandableListAdapter return sepcific Child, not all of them

Tags: android, view, return-value, expandablelistadapter

I have a class that extends **BaseExpandableListAdapter** :

```
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild,
        View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    Filter filter = (Filter) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.exp_list_child, null);
    }
    TextView tv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.child_tv);
    tv.setText(filter.toString());



    tv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.child_sub_tv);
    tv.setText(filter.getType());

    if(!filter.getType().endsWith("ExportPin"))
        // I dont want to return antyhing

    return convertView;
}
```

As you can see I create a `TextView` and everything but I don't want to return it if the type of the filter does not end with "`ExportPin`" (see if statement at the end).

I can't return `null` and I dont want to return an empty list item.

In my class I also have `getChildrenCount()`, `getGroupCount()` ...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [official documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html), an `Adapter` should not be in charge of filtering the data :

> An Adapter object acts as a bridge between an AdapterView and the underlying data for that view. The Adapter provides access to the data items. The Adapter is also responsible for making a View for each item in the data set.

You have to filter your data before putting them in your `Cursor`, then the `Adapter` will render the needed view to be display the data inside the `ListView`

Comment: Thanks for you answer.I put them in my cursor via a URI, how can I do that then ?

Comment: Your URI should filter your data, or you should made the filtering process by yourself (looping over the items in the Cursor or something). Do this in the constructor of your `BaseExpandableListAdapter` or when you instanciate your `Cursor`.

Comment: If everything is ok for you now, don't forget to Accept, Up Vote, etc... ;)

Comment: Yes don't worry Ill do it as soon as I get it :) Im stil stuck but itll work!

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you should filter the data before passing it to the adapter, (or in adapter constructor) so that the adapter to use only the filtered already data.